# Create a text file in document library using csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I need to create a file in document library using CSOM, It is not like uploading a file from our local system. It should be created using code and uploaded to sharepoint library.

Is it possible?

Comment: You want to write code Javascript or c#?

Comment: I want to do it using C#,

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `FileCreationInformation` to create a file.

Try the below code:

```
FileCreationInformation createFile = new FileCreationInformation();
createFile.Url = "test.txt";
//use byte array to set content of the file
string somestring = "hello there";
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(somestring);

createFile.Content = toBytes; 

List spList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File addedFile = spList.RootFolder.Files.Add(createFile);
context.Load(addedFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();

ListItem item = addedFile.ListItemAllFields;
item["Title"] = "File generated using Code";
item.Update();
ctx.Load(item);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine("File generated using code");
```

Comment: Thanks, can you pls also tell me how would I update the text in text file.
I mean it should have previous text and also next time updating it should append some text to the file

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file in memory and save that to your document library.

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://my.sharepoint.com/");

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Dummy text");
        writer.Flush();

        stream.Position = 0;
        var fileUrl = "/Documents/MyDummyFile.txt";

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, stream, true);
    }
}
```

Key here is the `SaveBinaryDirect` method. More info on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538285

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
public static void UploadLogFileIntoDocumentLibrary(ClientContext ctx, Web oweb, string FilePath,string FileName)
        {
            try
            {
                #region Create File in Site Asset > Visitor Logs folder
                //Get Server Relative URL of SiteAssets and Hit to Visitor Logs folder
                Folder oFolder = oweb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/SiteAssets/Visitor Logs");
                //Create a file
                FileCreationInformation oCreateFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                oCreateFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
                oCreateFile.Url = FileName;
                oCreateFile.Overwrite = true;
                //Add a created file to Given path
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File fileToUpload = oFolder.Files.Add(oCreateFile);
                ctx.Load(fileToUpload);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                //Delete the Temp created file
                System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath);
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here i am uploading text file inside the Folder so if its not required u can remove the **Visitor Logs** folder name